# Error in python train and test : How to fix "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, typeerror

I'm trying to write a code where, a dataset is divided into train and test. The main train part will be divided into train and cross validation. Using K- fold value, I want to run the code such that the main train set is divided into as many folds(or groups, depending on the value of folds that we mention) as we want and gives (folds-1) groups to the divided train set and the remaining to cross validation. Eg, if there are 3 folds, then the main train is divided into three groups: g1,g2,g3. first, g1+g2 is taken as train and g3 is cross validation, then, g2+g3 is train and g1 is cross validation and so on to find the accuracy and hence the best K value.

The logic that I have used is to divide the main train depending on number of folds and use random choice on it. so one group is chosen from the 'split_list' function and given to cross validation. the rest is given to train (main train-cross validation).

import random
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

def split_list(x_train, folds):

```
length = len(x_train)

return  random.choices([ x_train[i*length // folds: (i+1)*length // folds] 
         for i in range(folds) ])
def Random_Search(x_train,y_train,classifier, params, folds):

trainscores = []
cvscores = []

for k in tqdm(params['n_neighbors']):

    trainscores_folds = []
    cvscores_folds = []

    for j in range(0, folds):   

        cv_indices = split_list(list(x_train), folds)
        train_indices = list(set(list(range(1, len(x_train)))) - 
                         set(cv_indices))
```

Error that I'm getting:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-808deaf8461e> in <module>

      8 params = {'n_neighbors':sorted(random.sample(range(1,50),10))}

      9 folds = 9

---> 10 trainscores,cvscores = Random_Search(X_train, y_train, neigh, params, folds)

     11 plt.plot(params['n_neighbors'],trainscores, label='train cruve')

     12 plt.plot(params['n_neighbors'],cvscores, label='cv cruve')

<ipython-input-113-fc0b09f4ad82> in Random_Search(x_train, y_train, classifier, params, folds)

     14         for j in range(0, folds):

     15             cv_indices = split_list(list(x_train), folds)

---> 16             train_indices = list(set(list(range(1, len(x_train)))) - set(cv_indices))

     17 # selecting the data points based on the train_indices and test_indices

     18             X_train = x_train[train_indices]

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you try to make there but maybe the problem is on that **train_indices list** is show like the output what a list but you have one list what contain a list of items so he do not know how to read that list. he expected items not list of items.

So you have a main list what contain one list of items but he expected to found items not another list of items.